# How to execute multiple python scripts inside same docker container?

Tags: docker, pycharm

I have Flask project that contains some `util`  scripts for testing various endpoints.

If I set Python interpreter to be used as previously built image(*my-flask-app*), when I run my Flask app, it starts new container. However, If I run my util scripts, they can't make request to my Flask app since these scripts are **running inside an other container**. PyCharm executes them inside another container over and over again.

What is the approach of starting a server and then executing scripts to be able to make request to my Flask server ? Any idea ?

Comment: Why can't they make requests to your Flask application?  How are you configuring the server and utility containers, what URL are you trying to connect to, and what error do you get?  (Either starting a second container or running the utility scripts directly from the host are both reasonable things to do here.)

Comment: Because if you configure docker as remote python interpreter, every execution of any script in whole project results in new container spawned like `55371ce80e74:python3.6 -u /usr/src/app/main.py` `32e41ce50e74:python3.6 -u /usr/src/app/util/get_index.py` and so on...

Comment: Why is a new container per script execution bad?  Why not use a virtual environment (being much lighter-weight, not an isolated filesystem or network setup, and not generally requiring administrator privileges)?

Comment: For easier and same environment setup on every other person developing for this service, we use `Dockerfile`. Although virtualenv is good, there are some system specific files and commands that are missing on personal computers. But the question is about Docker here.